# Adding a cout statement corrects output?

Tags: c++, cout

I've run into this problem multiple times now and was wondering if someone could explain why it happens? Here I am writing a program that outputs the runtime of different sorting operations to a table. When I add a the "Why does this make it work" cout statement, it works. Without it, it does not and the indentation is thrown off.

```
 cout << "Size Selection    Insert    Bubble     Shell     Merge  Heapsort Quicksort       STL" << endl;

  for(int i = 50; i <= 6400; i *= 2) { // Prints table
    cout << "Why does this make it work" << endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // Creates random vector
      v.push_back(rand());
    }

    vector<int>& arr = v;

    // arr = &v;
    cout << setw(4) << i;

    start = clock();
    SelectionSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    InsertionSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    BubbleSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    ShellSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    MergeSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    HeapSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    QuickSort(arr);
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;

    start = clock();
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    cout << setw(10) << clock() - start;
  }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: That's the only code that ends a line, right? You just need to output an `endl` somewhere.

Comment: You don't reset your array before each sort. They have a much easier time sorting it after `SelectionSort`. Edit: Unless, of course, they take a copy of the array?

Comment: @sftrabbit That would be done by using a reference of the vector v correct? e.g.
    vector<int>& arr = v;
    SelectionSort(arr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the "Why does this make it work" line is the only one containing an endl. So without the endl the console wraps the line when your text reaches the end of the window (it doesn't really change lines, it only wraps the current one).

Most likely what looks like a new line contains some remains of the "previous" line and therefore the text doesn't look as expected.

With the endl you're changing to the next line and the text really starts at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. I don't know why I couldn't think of that on my own. haha Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your example don't give you your desired answer is, `std::ostream` do not send every single output to the output, instead it will cache data and only send it to output when its internal cache is full or when you call `flush`, also `std::endl` will call `flush` for you! and cause you see your output. try to replace it with `cout.flush()` and you will see every thing will go fine!